# When does the `newlines` attribute get set in universal newlines mode?

Tags: python, line-endings

I have a text file with Windows-style line terminators (`\r\n`) which I open in universal newlines mode (Python 2.7). I would expect the `newlines` attribute to be set after the first call to the `readline()` method, but apparently this is not the case:

```
>>> f=open('test_crlf', 'rU')
>>> f.newlines
>>> f.readline()
'foo\n'
>>> f.newlines
>>> f.readline()
'bar\n'
>>> f.newlines
'\r\n'
```

On the other hand, the `newlines` attribute gets set after the first call to `readline()` on a file with Unix-style line endings.

What is the general rule? When should I expect the `newlines` attribute to be set?

Answer (score 3):

As per [pep-0278](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0278/)

> A file object that has been opened in universal newline mode gets
>       a new attribute "newlines" which reflects the newline convention
>       used in the file.  The value for this attribute is one of None (no
>       newline read yet), "\r", "\n", "\r\n" or a tuple containing all the
>       newline types seen.

As an example :

```
>>> fp = open('test.txt', 'wb')
>>> fp.write('a line ending with a cr \r')
>>> fp.write('a line ending with an lf \n')
>>> fp.write('a line ending with a crlf \r\n')
>>> fp.close()
>>> fp = open('test.txt', 'rU')
>>> fp.newlines
>>> fp.readline()
'a line ending with a cr \n'
>>> fp.newlines
>>> fp.readline()
'a line ending with an lf \n'
>>> fp.newlines
('\r', '\n')
>>> fp.readline()
'a line ending with a crlf \n'
>>> fp.newlines
('\r', '\n')
>>> fp.readline()
''
>>> fp.newlines
('\r', '\n', '\r\n')
```

As you can see, only after the last readline() which returns '', does it actually register the \r\n. So it must be capturing newline types "seen" only on the next iteration.

Comment: having the newlines attribute i.e. `hasattr(open, "newlines")` should suffice to know that universal lines is supported

Comment: Yeah, this is what I observed, too. It would be interesting to look at the behaviour of other implementations, such as PyPy or Jython.

Comment: I was re-reading this answer today. Did you notice that `\n` is registered right away, while `\r` and `\r\n` are only registered on the following iteration?

Comment: Yes, I'm not sure why though. I just figured the variable is there just to see what characters were actually converted to universal \n. I found the unit tests for that patch, but could not figure out its behaviour - you might have some luck [univnewlines_tests](http://bugs.python.org/file3727/test_univnewlines.py)

Comment: Thanks for the link. It is pretty clear to me that the `newlines` attribute is not tested after each `readline()`, so maybe (MAYBE) this is a bug that went undetected? I'll get in touch with upstream.

Comment: @Arek'Fu Is that fixed now?